# Reporting Services - Reading the report name by expression, which has been selected in Action

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, bids

I have a RDL report and on one of the Textboxes in the Tablix I have a reference to another report in the current project.

I want to display in a tool tip the selected report name, which has been selected (from the list of existing reports in the current project) in Actions.

Is this possible?

Edit:
I tried using built in code expression, I couldn't figure out the correct way to write the code though (no intelisense support). This is the approach I tried:

```
ReportItems("TextBox6").GetType()
```

Thank you in advance,

Eddie

Comment: did you try using a built-in code expression?

Comment: @vondip, yes I've tried the get out the elememt by using ReportItems("TextBox6").GetType()... with no luck